# How to combine multiple external REST API services in the same network using Django

Tags: django, nginx, flask, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have a central Django REST API and want to serve multiple different machine learning models which I package as individual Flask REST apps. In order to provide a unified REST interface I would like to use the Django REST server as relay / proxy to the individual Flask services. All services are currently built and deployed using docker swarm/compose.

What I currently can do is build for each individual Flask app the URL outlets in urls.py and then write code for each GET/POST method in Django to call the Flask outlet. However, I was wondering if in Django I could simply redirect all REST calls requesting:

http://localhost/api/v1/model1

To the Flask app providing model1 and the Flask app then response for example to a request of

http://localhost/api/v1/model1/submitData

without needing Django to explicitly define http://localhost/api/v1/model1/submitData in urls.py.

Alternatively I was thinking using Nginx to redirect all calls to http://localhost/api/v1/model1 to the Flask app instead of Django which is the default for http://localhost in my case.

I hope the question is clear enough. Bottom line is that I am looking for the most convenient way to have a single REST interface but some REST services should run on individual docker images as Flask Apps.

Comment: I think using Django to simply proxy these calls is an overhead with no benefits. So, configuring nginx would be the easiest way.

Comment: I agree with Marco, the desired behaviour is what reverse proxy does. The right tool for this is nginx/apache, not Django.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. this would certainly be more direct. one would still need to write code in django to announce the proxy rest services via swagger or so. but certainly less overhead.